# don't save if the textfield is empty

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am working on a college project and I was having this problem that I don't know how to fix. When the user clicks on the Register button his information will be saved but if he didn't fill in the blanks he will get an error message. But the problem is that it will save an empty textfield in the CoreData. So I want to "Catch" that and give them an error without saving an empty textfield to the CoreData.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewRegister: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPhone: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtCity: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnRegister(_ sender: Any) {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let newContact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)
        newContact.setValue(txtName.text, forKey: "name")
        newContact.setValue(txtUsername.text, forKey: "username")
        newContact.setValue(txtPassword.text, forKey: "password")
        newContact.setValue(txtPhone.text , forKey: "phone")
        newContact.setValue(txtAddress.text , forKey: "address")
        newContact.setValue(txtCity.text , forKey: "city")
        do{
            try context.save()
            print ("Saved")
        }
        catch{
            print ("Error")
        }

        if txtCity.text == "" || txtAddress.text == "" || txtPhone.text == "" || txtPassword.text == "" || txtUsername.text == "" || txtName.text == ""
        {
            // Create the alert controller
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ops!!", message: "Please fill in the information", preferredStyle: .alert)

            // Create the actions
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("OK Pressed")
            }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
            }

            // Add the actions
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)

            // Present the controller
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            txtName.text = ""
            txtUsername.text = ""
            txtPassword.text = ""
            txtPhone.text = ""
            txtAddress.text = ""
            txtCity.text = ""


            // Create the alert controller
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Successfully Registered!", message: "Thank you for registering in our application", preferredStyle: .alert)

            // Create the actions
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("OK Pressed")
            }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
                UIAlertAction in
                NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
            }

            // Add the actions
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)

            // Present the controller
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Why don't you call your contact initialization and save-call in your "else" code part. Because the if-conditions checked before, whether the values arent valid?

Comment: You are the one who is saying `context.save()` unconditionally. If you don't want to do that then don't do that.

Comment: @matt i am new in Xcode so please help

Comment: Don't enable the Register button until all fields are valid. See for instance the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Comment: But are you new in thinking? If you don't want to walk into a wall, you don't bang into the wall and then walk around it; you walk around it _before_ you would bang into it. You are saving and _then_ checking to see whether you should have saved. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I only can repeat the comment by @Lepidopteron: Why don't you call your contact initialization and save-call in your "else" code part?

Like this?

```
@IBAction func btnRegister(_ sender: Any) {        

    if txtCity.text == "" || txtAddress.text == "" || txtPhone.text == "" || txtPassword.text == "" || txtUsername.text == "" || txtName.text == ""
    {
        // Create the alert controller
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Ops!!", message: "Please fill in the information", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create the actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
        }

        // Add the actions
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Present the controller
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let newContact = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Users", into: context)
        newContact.setValue(txtName.text, forKey: "name")
        newContact.setValue(txtUsername.text, forKey: "username")
        newContact.setValue(txtPassword.text, forKey: "password")
        newContact.setValue(txtPhone.text , forKey: "phone")
        newContact.setValue(txtAddress.text , forKey: "address")
        newContact.setValue(txtCity.text , forKey: "city")
        do{
            try context.save()
            print ("Saved")
        }
        catch{
             print ("Error")
        }


        txtName.text = ""
        txtUsername.text = ""
        txtPassword.text = ""
        txtPhone.text = ""
        txtAddress.text = ""
        txtCity.text = ""


        // Create the alert controller
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Successfully Registered!", message: "Thank you for registering in our application", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // Create the actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
        }

        // Add the actions
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Present the controller
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```